# idiomatic way for `class<T>` to `class<const T>` conversion operator

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading, idioms

Suppose there is a template class `template <class T> myclass;`.

Is there an idiomatic way to allow conversion of objects of non-const `T` to objects of `const T`?

Basically, I want the following conversion to happen implicitly:

```
void f(myclass<const int> x);

myclass<int> a;
f(a); // should compile
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

It appears that the answer is very trivial (and the question is quite silly) but there is something very conceptual involved (at least for me).

I was under the impression that I need to conditionally enable a conversion operator because a conversion operator from `myclass<const T>` to `myclass<const T>` doesn't make any sense, i.e. I need to declare the conversion operator if and only if `T` was `const` qualified. I was expecting the compiler to complain about a redundant conversion operator.

Now given that the compiler is happy with the identity conversion operator which converts type `X` to `X`, what's the difference between the assignment operator or the copy constructor and the identity conversion operator?

MSVC throws a warning for an identity conversion operator. This isn't great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a conversion operator that returns a `myclass` with the type const qualified.  That looks like

```
template<typename T>
struct myclass
{
    T foo;
    operator myclass<const T>() { return myclass<const T>{foo}; }
};
```

and then in

```
int main() 
{ 
    myclass<int> a{42};
    f(a); // should compile
}
```

the compiler will implicitly call it for you.

---

If you already have a `myclass<const int>` and you pass it to `f` you don't have to worry about any ambiguity since the copy constructor is an exact match so that is what is called.  However, if you do want to disable the conversion operator when `T` is already `const` then you can use

```
template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<U>, bool> = true> 
operator myclass<const U>() { return myclass<const U>{foo}; }
```

Comment: @Yashas In that case "const collapsing" happens can you'll still get a `const T`.  `myclass<const int>`'s `operator myclass<const T>` would be come `operator myclass<const const int>` which collapses to `operator myclass<const int>`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. A conversion operator for converting from `X` to `X` doesn't make much sense? It would have to be an assignment operator?

Comment: I thought I would need to conditionally enable the conversion operator.

Comment: @Yashas _"what if T is already const qualified?"_ It will compile, if [`foo` is properly initialized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78800d8d0b34d276).

Comment: @Yashas If you already have a `myclass<const T>` then it isn't going to call the conversion operator since the copy constructor is an exact match.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you should add that to your answer since that was the original source for my question. I have added a note to the question.

Comment: @Yashas I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I've run into a problem. MSVC throws a warning `will not be called for implicit or explicit conversions`. I don't want this. It's thrown when `T` is already `const` qualified.

Comment: @Yashas In that case you can conditionally allow it only when `T` is not `const` like `template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<U>, bool> = true>
    operator myclass<const T>() { return myclass<const T>{foo}; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry to bother but I think your previous comment is useful for future viewers as well and might be worth adding to your answer.